# Sitecore Solr - IndexSchema no uniqueKey specified in schema

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a small extra question that I believe is related to
[Missing Id field in Solr index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970849/missing-id-field-in-solr-index)  a little bit.

The issue is that search result contain duplication items (that was edited), amount of item depends on edit count. 
It is seems like sitecore doesn't remove old item from Solr index (no item versions).
Is it Sitecore issue or some specific Solr behavior ?

I see in Solr log next message may be it is connected:

> WARN null IndexSchema no uniqueKey specified in schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `<uniqueKey>` tag in your `schema.xml' file in every Solr core:

```xml
<uniqueKey>_uniqueid</uniqueKey>
```

It should be directly under the root `<schema>` tag (not inside `<fields>` or any other tag).

If you follow the guide for enabling Solr with Sitecore, it should be included in your `schema.xml` automatically.

Comment: I don't know how it is possible but <uniqueKey>_uniqueid</uniqueKey> was missed

Comment: I was getting same warning in Solr logs & tried the solution, but if I define the <uniqueKey> direct under <schema> & reload the core it fails.